# Why does jersey doesn't pick up my PATH and give me a 404?

Tags: scala, maven, jetty, jersey

I am developping a simple rest service with jersey and scala, mainly for learning purpose. I currently have the following configured

```
package org.michaelangelomanager.restservice.rest

import javax.ws.rs.GET
import javax.ws.rs.Path
import javax.ws.rs.Produces
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType

@Path("/drawing")
class DrawingResource {

  @GET
  @Produces(Array(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN))
  def someText() = {
    "Some text" 
  }
}
```

And my web.xml look like this

```
<display-name>org.michaelangelomanager.restservice</display-name>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MichaelAngeloManager</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>org.michaelangelomanager.restservice.rest</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MichaelAngeloManager</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then when I do a mvn jetty:run in a console I get the following output

```
[INFO] Starting jetty 6.1.26 ...
2012-02-06 14:46:26.149:INFO::jetty-6.1.26
2012-02-06 14:46:26.296:INFO::No Transaction manager found - if your webapp requires one, please configure one.
6 fevr. 2012 14:46:26 com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig init
INFO: Scanning for root resource and provider classes in the packages:
  org.michaelangelomanager.restservice.rest
6 fevr. 2012 14:46:26 com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig logClasses
INFO: Root resource classes found:
  class org.michaelangelomanager.restservice.rest.DrawingResource
6 fevr. 2012 14:46:26 com.sun.jersey.api.core.ScanningResourceConfig init
INFO: No provider classes found.
6 fevr. 2012 14:46:26 com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.11 12/09/2011 10:27 AM'
2012-02-06 14:46:27.206:INFO::Started SelectChannelConnector@0.0.0.0:8080
[INFO] Started Jetty Server
```

So obviously my root is picked up. But then I open my browser and go to http://localhost:8080/drawing and I get a 404.

What I am missing here? Every example I found didn't need more than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, all that trouble because I didn't really knew how jetty:run worked. See, the jetty maven plugin run your site under a context app that correspond to the artifact id.

What that mean in plain language is that if in your pom.xml you have

```
<artifactId>myfabulousapp</artifactId>
```

you will access you apps with http://localhost:8080/myfabulousapp and not juste http://localhost:8080 like I previously assumed.

To prevent this, simply configure you plugin like this

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>6.1.26</version>
    <configuration>
        <!-- THAT LINE -->
        <contextPath>/</contextPath>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

That will teach me to only skim the documentation